# Getting into the job market as an autodidact

Tags: job-search, new-job, recruitment

As a self-guided autodidactic student with a lot of experience as a freelancer, what are the best ways to find a good job?

Working on your portfolio such as participating in Google's Summer of Code, contributing to Open Source projects, competing in coding competitions seems to be vital, but what more could be done?

Please keep in mind that in this scenario the student does not have an official degree of any sort. What strategy would be advisable to target a job at one of the "big player" IT companies?

Comment: Note: Since I live in a conservative environment where importance is only given to jobs at top IT companies, first jobs at startup is not an option.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I'm pretty sure he's using "fresher" in the Indian sense. It means (afaik) people who are out of university and starting their first job; not first-year college students.

Comment: I completely reworded this interesting question to come off as less negative and fit the rules of the Workplace. How do I apply to get this opened again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you can do the stuff you're describing, you'll have no problem finding work.  The software developer business is pretty cut and dried - you can either do it or you can't. A lot of companies have learned to ignore degrees.

It couldn't hurt to read the [Google Careers - How We Hire](http://www.google.com/about/careers/lifeatgoogle/hiringprocess/) page, if you haven't already looked this over.

> "What strategy should I make if I am targeting to get my first job after finishing education at top IT companies like Google, Microsoft, Facebook...?"

Targeting a company is less useful that targeting a problem.  What is it you want to do, and who else does it? If you try to get a job 'with a company', they'll put you in some nasty area you're good at but not happy with. If you focus on what you want to do, you'll find an employer that needs that.  They could be big, a start up, or a 100 year old insurance company.  Who cares?

> "Since I live in a conservative environment"

This needs further elaboration. Presumably this means the way that hiring managers evaluate candidates. There are ways to break through that, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

> So, What strategy should I make if I am targeting to get my first job
>   after finishing education at top IT companies like Google, Microsoft,
>   Facebook...?

It sounds like you are planning to "finish your education" by dropping out. That's unfortunate, since it may very well limit your opportunities.

Your strategy is to find a job at one of the companies that you feel are "top IT" that doesn't require a college education.

You could do that by finding a position within those companies where education isn't required. They may have a few positions like that, although you wouldn't likely be competing "with freshers from top universities" in those cases, you would just be competing with others lacking a college degree.

Or you could find a way to make yourself attractive enough to those companies such that they will overlook your lack of degree and hire you.

To take this route, you could become a prominent speaker at conferences attended by representatives of these companies. Or, you could build a product/website that gains enough hits/purchases/credibility from a wide enough audience that it attracts the attention of these companies. Or, perhaps you have a friend in your personal network that works at one of these companies who could vouch for your abilities.

While it's not absolutely necessary to have a degree to be hired by a top IT company, you seriously hurt your chances by not having one.

Comment: Thanks for answer. And yes I talked about the second part. "How can I make myself attractive so that they can ignore the degree part"